# Batch to Delete characters from Folder Names

Tags: batch-file, directory, rename

I need to try and make a Batch File that deletes all characters up to the first bracket in all folders in directory.

Example:

```
 Main Directory
 -Folder123 [abc123]
 -Folder321 [123abc]
```

I need the folder names like so:

```
 Main Directory
 -[abc123]
 -[123abc]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Take a look at the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), which is capable of capturing the output of a command; then check out the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), whose output you may want to capture, particularly when using the options `/B` (bare output list) and `/A:D` (filter for directories); finally, check out the [`move` command](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html), which can rename directories; so: `for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=[]" %%I in ('dir /B /A:D "D:\ROOT\*[*]"') do (move "D:\ROOT\%%~I[%%~J]" "[%%~J]")`...

Answer (score 0):

I thought you'd already accepted an answer for this question earlier, however here is my solution for your resubmitted question:

```bat
@For /D %%A In ("Main Directory\*[*]") Do @(Set "_=%%~nxA" & Call Ren "%%~A" "%%_:*[=[%%")
```